# PHPUnit locking objects

Tags: php, codeigniter, tdd, phpunit

I had a question about PHPUnit and how it seems to lock objects and if I am testing in an incorrect fashion or if it is just something on PHPUnit. Here is my test code

```
$t = Track::create(array('name'=>'test track'));
$this->assertEquals(0, $t->student_tracks, 'Empty track should be empty');
$st = StudentTrack::create(array('track_id' => $t->id, 'completion'=>'0')); //Add item
$this->assertEquals(1, $t->student_tracks, 'There should now be something in this track');
```

The last assert fails.  Everything in the database looks correct and if I print_r both objects($t and $st) it shows the correct information. After looking into the issues I found that if I add a clone before the first assert it works:

```
$t = Track::create(array('name'=>'test track'));
$cl = clone $t;
$this->assertEquals(0, $cl->student_tracks, 'Empty track should be empty');
$st = StudentTrack::create(array('track_id' => $t->id, 'completion'=>'0')); //Add item
$this->assertEquals(1, $t->student_tracks, 'There should now be something in this track');
```

So my questions are:

1. Does PHPUnit lock the object so I cannot use it after an assert?
2. Am I testing wrong, should I only have one assert per test?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's fine to have multiple assertions in a test, but I think your problem is more that you're expecting the $t object to be modified, but the StudentTrack factory method is not passed $t, so it's very unlikely to modify it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does PHPUnit lock the object so I cannot use it after an assert?

No. PHPUnit does nothing in that direction.

> Am I testing wrong, should I only have one assert per test?

You're probably testing wrong, but not because of the number of asserts. You can have multiple asserts per test, however actually, in your case this smells a bit like you want to use a [*Data Provider*](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.8/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.data-providers).

```
class DataTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider provider
     */
    public function testStudentTracks($track, $expected, $message)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $track->student_tracks, $message);
    }

    public function provider()
    {
        return array(
          array(TrackTestCreator::createWithNoStudenTracks(), 0, 'Empty track should be empty'),
          array(TrackTestCreator::createWithOneStudenTracks(), 1, 'There should now be something in this track'),
        );
    }
}
```

A key point in tests is that you keep them simple. E.g. most likely you're doing an error creating your objects, so you test something you might expect but you don't know that is. Therefore the tests fail. Then you're puzzled.

That is why in the example I give I have created two more global function that say what they return. You need to implement each of them, if you do that isolated, you are more likely finding the error.